# Parameter Layout in ASP.NET Report Viewer (SSRS 2016)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

The 2016 SQL Server Report Builder allows users to arrange how the parameters will be laid out when the report renders.  This gives you much more flexibility than previous versions which just shoved the parameters into a 2-column stack at the top of your report.

However it seems that the ASP.NET Report Viewer does not honor the layout that I'm specifying.  For example, if I layout my parameters in 4x3 rows, the rendered report in the ASP.NET Report Viewer still shows the parameters in a 2x6 grid.

Does ASP.NET ReportViewer just not support custom parameter layouts for remote reports?

FYI: I'm using Version 11 of the ReportViewer.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Report.Viewer/11.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to be using v13. Here's the nuget install line:

Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview

Here's the msdn webpage:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/01a821c4-2920-400c-be03-93d26c749bb1.aspx

If SQL Server Data Tools or SQL Server Management Studio for SQL 2016 is installed, make sure it’s updated to the latest version. Earlier versions of SSDT incorrectly gac’ed certain dlls which conflict with the Report Viewer Control. You may need to manually delete the V13 dll's  from \windows\assembly\gac_msil to permanently remove them.
How to uninstall
gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

gacutil /u "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /f

If you get Unable to uninstall: assembly is required by one or more applications
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/873195